# How to merge[union] one column[field] data in MySQL!

Tags: mysql

E.g:  `DISTINCT file_sn` and got the `merge[union,unique] all_files result:`

```
user_id  file_sn all_files[char] 
1        1       01 02 05
2        1       02 05
3        1       05 06 07 08
4        1       10 11 12 15
```

So,I want to `merge[union]` the column： `all_files` so I could get the `unique all_files` data like:

```
01 02 05 06 07 08 10 11 12 15
```

Thank you very much~~

**[UPDATE]**
My query to get the all all_files query:

```
SELECT file_sn, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT all_files SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM `myTable`
GROUP BY file_sn
```

It will return:

```
01 02 05 02 05 05 06 07 08 05 06 07 08
```

Comment: Poor conception leads to something like this. You're breaking the first normal form. Modify your table structure, it will be much easier.

Comment: I don't know what all_files represents.  You might want to consider normalizing your database so that each item in all_files is its own row in a separate table.  That would greatly simplify this problem.